# How do I store a SQL statement into a variable

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am currently facing a problem here. I have a column called "DESC1" in a table called "Master". I'm trying to retrieve the value based on something along the lines of this...

```
"Select DESC1 FROM Master WHERE '" & TextBox1.Text & "' "
```

And I'm trying to display on the excel beside both correctString1 and correctString

```
 oWB.Sheets(1).Range("A2", "K2").Insert(Shift:=Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
 oWB.Sheets(1).Range("E2").Value = " " & correctString1 & " : " &  correctString & " "
```

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: I think your question is about `excel-vba` instead of `vb.net`, If yes please edit your tag ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim reader As SqlDataReader

cmd.CommandText = "Select DESC1 FROM Master WHERE '" & TextBox1.Text & "' "
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()    
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
' Data is accessible through the DataReader object here. 

If reader.HasRows Then 
        Do While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0) _
              & vbTab & reader.GetString(1))
        Loop 
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
    End If   
sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Considering first column is `NUMBER` type and second column is `VARCHAR`

[Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

**==Update==**

```
connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
```

[See more](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-sqldatareader.htm)

Comment: Yes it is! But which is the variable I should use to place in my excel sheet?

Comment: @ChloeAllison after `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()` add `reader.read()` and you can get the values using `reader("ColumnName")`.

Comment: @jWeaver I've tried it but it shows an error of "Keyword not supported 'provider' ". I've tried changing SqlCommand and SqlDataReader to OledbCommand and OledbDataReader instead but it shows that no such columns/rows for "DESC1" are found

Comment: @jWeaver I've tried it but still boils down to the same error.      oWB.Sheets(1).Range("E2").Value = " " & correctString1 & " : " & correctString & " " & reader.Item("DESC1") & " "

Comment: You said you are getting error  `Keyword not supported 'provider' `. As you can see, It saying about keyword `provider`. And, in my code, I didn't used any keyword `provider`. Probably, in your connection string, you have mentioned `provider` or somewhere above.